# Interval days between category in sql

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to calculate the difference between 1st purchased and 2nd purchased on each category?

For example, I have the dataset here:

```
trx_id  user_pin category    date
    1   "jak"   "smartphone" "2018-01-01"
    1   "jak"   "groceries"  "2018-01-01"
    1   "jak"   "health"     "2018-01-01"
    1   "jak"   "virtual"    "2018-01-01"
    2   "mei"   "groceries"  "2018-01-01"
    2   "mei"   "virtual"    "2018-01-01"
    4   "jak"   "smartphone" "2018-05-02"
    8   "mei"   "groceries"  "2018-09-02"
    8   "mei"   "virtual"    "2018-09-02"
```

I want to know the difference date between purchase and the result like this:

```
trx_id  user_pin     category     date        next_buy      diff
        1   "jak"   "smartphone" "2018-01-01" "2018-05-02"  121
        1   "jak"   "groceries"  "2018-01-01" "2018-05-02"  121
        1   "jak"   "health"     "2018-01-01" "2018-05-02"  121
        1   "jak"   "virtual"    "2018-01-01" "2018-05-02"  121
        4   "jak"   "smartphone" "2018-05-02"  "null"       null
        2   "mei"   "groceries"  "2018-01-01"  "2018-09-02" 244
        2   "mei"   "virtual"    "2018-01-01"  "2018-09-02" 244
        5   "mei"   "groceries"  "2018-09-02"  "null"       null
        5   "mei"   "virtual"    "2018-09-02"  "null"       null
```

How's the query?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) I have no idea what the relationship is between the desired results and the question.

Comment: Amen; add a tag that states which database system this is, and if it's mysql make it clear what version it is

Comment: I use postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming SQL Server you could do something like this with a CTE and an outer apply to get the next record:

```
 WITH mydataranked AS (
      Select trx_id,user_pin, category, purchase_date, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by user_pin, category ORDER by purchase_Date asc) as myrank
      from mydata
      )


 Select trx_id, user_pin, category, md.purchase_date, aa.purchase_date as next_buy, datediff(day, md.purchase_date, aa.purchase_date) as diff  
 from mydataranked md

  outer apply 
 (Select purchase_date from mydataranked md2 
  where md.user_pin=md2.user_pin and md.category=md.category and md2.myrank=md.myrank+1) aa
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I changed a little bit on your query in 'outer apply' since I use postgresql,  so I changed it to left join lateral and it works on me. Thanks man !

Comment: No problem - that's why Gordon asked for the SQL flavour. Each works slightly differently.